# columna autoincrementable de dos digitos

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo Una `tabla` **turnos** con una columna **turno** que esta auto incrementable pero quisiera colocarla con dos digitos.
ejemplo:
01
02
03
...
09
10
alguna idea de como llegar hacerlo?

Answer (score 3):

De esta forma podría ser:

```
 create table TURNOS ( 
 turno int(2) zerofill not null auto_increment,
 primary key(turno) );
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Gracias, no olvides votar positivo si la respuesta fue de tu ayuda :)

Comment: si lo se tengo que esperar para hacerlo